# How do I reverse the order of the pages in a pdf file using pyPdf?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have a pdf file "myFile.pdf". I would like to reverse the order of its pages using [pyPdf](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/). How?

Comment: @Tom: What I've tried so far was kind of similar to nosklo's answer. We both had the same bug (I/O operation on closed file). The reason is of course that we both used `output_pdf` after closing it. I've just fixed his solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
output_pdf = PdfFileWriter()

with open(r'input.pdf', 'rb') as readfile:
    input_pdf = PdfFileReader(readfile)
    total_pages = input_pdf.getNumPages()
    for page in xrange(total_pages - 1, -1, -1):
        output_pdf.addPage(input_pdf.getPage(page))
    with open(r'output.pdf', "wb") as writefile:
        output_pdf.write(writefile)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped me to identify my error causing I/O Operation on a closed file: You have to keep the PdfFileReader open untill PdfFileWriter is done writing.  (Counter-intuitively, to me).  Presumably this is because the writer doesn't actually seek the data from the reader's pages until it needs to, for improved performance.

Comment: This obviously works, but wouldn't it make more sense to use `range(total_pages, 0, -1)` instead?
That way you'd eventually even be able access the pages by number at any time of the iteration without confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for sharing suggestions. I used them and edited a bit to make the interface more graphical when selecting and saving a file. New to all of this and what I added might not be efficient or clean, but it worked for me and thought to share.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import ntpath
import os


output_pdf = PdfFileWriter()

# grab the location of the file path sent
def path_leaf(path):
    head, tail = ntpath.split(path)
    return head

# graphical file selection
def grab_file_path():
    # use dialog to select file
    file_dialog_window = tk.Tk()
    file_dialog_window.withdraw()  # hides the tk.TK() window
    # use dialog to select file
    grabbed_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    return grabbed_file_path


# file to be reversed
filePath = grab_file_path()

# open file and read
with open(filePath, 'rb') as readfile:
    input_pdf = PdfFileReader(readfile)

    # reverse order one page at time
    for page in reversed(input_pdf.pages):
        output_pdf.addPage(page)

    # graphical way to get where to select file starting at input file location
    dirOfFileToBeSaved = path_leaf(filePath)
    locationOfFileToBeSaved=filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir=dirOfFileToBeSaved, initialfile='name of reversed file.pdf',title="Select or type file name and location", filetypes=[("pdf files", "*.pdf")])
    # write the file created
    with open(locationOfFileToBeSaved, "wb") as writefile:
        output_pdf.write(writefile)

# open the file when done
os.startfile(locationOfFileToBeSaved)
```

Answer (score 3):

As of (long before) January 2019, [pyPdf](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/) is no longer updated, and upon testing is not compatible with (at least) Python 3.6, and likely at all with Python 3:

```
In [1]: import pyPdf
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-bba5a42e9137> in <module>
----> 1 import pyPdf

c:\temp\envminecart\lib\site-packages\pyPdf\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from pdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
      2 __all__ = ["pdf"]

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdf'
```

(Moving the `__all__` assignment above the `import` fixes this specific problem, but other `SyntaxError`s due to Python 2 syntax then pop up.)

Fortunately, its successor project, [PyPDF2](http://mstamy2.github.io/PyPDF2/), works cleanly on Python 3.6 (at least). It appears the core user-facing API was intentionally maintained to be compatible with pyPdf, so [nosklo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5425501) can be used in modern Python after a `pip install PyPDF2` just by changing to `PyPDF2` in the `import` statement, and switching `xrange` to `range`:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
output_pdf = PdfFileWriter()

with open(r'input.pdf', 'rb') as readfile:
    input_pdf = PdfFileReader(readfile)
    total_pages = input_pdf.getNumPages()
    for page in range(total_pages - 1, -1, -1):
        output_pdf.addPage(input_pdf.getPage(page))
    with open(r'output.pdf', "wb") as writefile:
        output_pdf.write(writefile)
```

I would also recommend the more Pythonic approach of just iterating over the pages directly using [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

output_pdf = PdfFileWriter()

with open('input.pdf', 'rb') as readfile:
    input_pdf = PdfFileReader(readfile)

    for page in reversed(input_pdf.pages):
        output_pdf.addPage(page)

    with open('output.pdf', "wb") as writefile:
        output_pdf.write(writefile)
```

I don't know if this `.pages` collection was available in the original `pyPdf`, but arguably it doesn't really matter much at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Works in 2023:

```py
from pypdf import PdfWriter, PdfReader
output_pdf = PdfWriter()

with open(r'input.pdf', 'rb') as readfile:
    input_pdf = PdfReader(readfile)
    total_pages = len(input_pdf.pages)
    for page in range(total_pages - 1, -1, -1):
        output_pdf.add_page(input_pdf.pages[page])
    with open(r'output.pdf', "wb") as writefile:
        output_pdf.write(writefile)
```