# How do I reverse multiple the order of multiple PDF files with pyPDF2?

Tags: python, macos, pypdf

## What I want to do

-I want to reverse the order of about 10 PDFs.

## What I have done

-I have found a very nice way of doing this here. (Great thanks to this post):
[How do I reverse the order of the pages in a pdf file using pyPdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425439/how-do-i-reverse-the-order-of-the-pages-in-a-pdf-file-using-pypdf)
-But this code was written for only one file.
-So I edited the code to something like below.

## My code

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import ntpath
import os
import glob


output_pdf = PdfFileWriter()

# grab the location of the file path sent
def path_leaf(path):
    head, tail = ntpath.split(path)
    return head

# graphical file selection
def grab_file_path():
    # use dialog to select file
    file_dialog_window = tk.Tk()
    file_dialog_window.withdraw()  # hides the tk.TK() window
    # use dialog to select file
    grabbed_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
    return grabbed_file_path


# file to be reversed
filePaths = grab_file_path()

# open file and read
for filePath in filePaths:
    with open(filePath, 'rb') as readfile:
        input_pdf = PdfFileReader(readfile)

        # reverse order one page at time
        for page in reversed(input_pdf.pages):
            output_pdf.addPage(page)

        # graphical way to get where to select file starting at input file location
        dirOfFileToBeSaved = os.path.join(path_leaf(filePath), 'reverse' + os.path.basename(filePath)) 
        # write the file created
        with open(dirOfFileToBeSaved, "wb") as writefile:
            output_pdf.write(writefile)
```

## Problem

-It did reverse the order.
-But it did not only reverse the order but also merged all the files.
-**e.g.**

```
A.pdf: page c, b, a    
B.pdf: page f, e, d  
C.pdf: page i, h, g
```

result would be like this

```
reverseA.pdf: page a, b, c  
reverseB.pdf: page a, b, c, d, e, f  
reverseC.pdf: page a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i
```

## My question

-How should I edit this code so that the files will not be merged?
-I am very new to python, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You keep adding pages to the same output_pdf, even though the pages are from different PDFs originally. You can solve this by adding

```
output_pdf = PdfFileWriter()
```

before starting with a new file. You would get:

```
...
# open file and read
for filePath in filePaths:
    output_pdf = PdfFileWriter()
    with open(filePath, 'rb') as readfile:
        input_pdf = PdfFileReader(readfile)
...
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: Hi Daniel, this did not work for me. I got the result pdf files, but all the pages were blank and white. Thank you for your suggestion :) And page numbers were the same as original file.

Comment: Are you sure you inserted the line at the correct spot? What do you mean that the page numbers (of the blank pages) were the same as the original file?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I meant that the result file contained the same number of pages as the original file (e.g. A.pdf), but it was blank.

Answer (score 0):

This seems an indentation issue. Your save instruction was indented to inner loop and not the outermost for loop. Try following which has the correct indentation.

```
# file to be reversed
filePaths = grab_file_path()

# open file and read
for filePath in filePaths:
    with open(filePath, 'rb') as readfile:
        input_pdf = PdfFileReader(readfile)

        # reverse order one page at time
        for page in reversed(input_pdf.pages):
            output_pdf.addPage(page)

    # graphical way to get where to select file starting at input file location
    dirOfFileToBeSaved = os.path.join(path_leaf(filePath), 'reverse' + os.path.basename(filePath)) 
    # write the file created
    with open(dirOfFileToBeSaved, "wb") as writefile:
        output_pdf.write(writefile)
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I got the result pdf files, but all the pages were blank and white. Thank you for your suggestion :)

Comment: And page numbers were the same as original file.

Comment: @XTJP, This solution address the issue that you mentioned in initial thread. If you have more questions then do mention it on the post so that someone can help.